# How to use php mail() function

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-5

I know this code will give error on local host and not working on live server.

As you can see i am trying to run this code for mail function. this function is running on my other site but working in this site. know this code will give error on local host but not showing error . may be some issue with the form . i do not know what exactly the error please tell me the issue.

```
function send-message()
{
      if(ISSET($_POST['submit'])) {
        $to        = "abc@example.com";
        $FROM_NAME= $_POST['name'];
        $cell = $_POST['cell'];
        $email     = $_POST['email'];
        $subject   = $_POST['subject'];
        $message   = $_POST['message'];
    
        $headers = "From:{$FROM_NAME} {$email} {$cell}";
        $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        if (!$result) {
          echo "error";
        }
        else{
          echo "sent";
        }
      }
  }
```

here is a form please address the error

```
<form method="post" id="contact-form" action="">
   <?PHP send-message(); ?> // function call here
   <div class="input-box mt-25">
       <label for="#">Full Name Here</label>
       <input type="text" name="name" placeholder=" Enter Name Here" required="">
       <i class="FAL FA-user"></i> //please ignore capital letter
    </div>
   <div class="input-box mt-25">
       <label for="#">Phone Number</label>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your phone number *" name="cell" required="" max length="11" min length="11">
        <i class="FAS FA-phone-square"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="input-box mt-25">
       <label for="#">I Would Like To Discuss</label>
       <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required="">
         <i class="far FA-envelope"></i>
   </div>
     <div class="input-box mt-25">
       <label for="#">Subject</label>
       <input name="subject" type="text" placeholder="Subject *" required="">
       <i class="FAS FA-book"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="input-box mt-25">
       <label for="#">Leave A Message</label>
       <text area name="message" id="#" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Write Message"></text area>
       <i class="FAL FA-pen-alt"></i>
   </div>
   <div class="submit-BTN text-left mt-20">
       <button type="submit" name="submit" class="main-BTN">Send Message</button>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is multiple errors in your code.

`send-message` does not seems to be a valid function name.

An other problem is about the `headers` part, check the [official php.net/mail documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) to see how to use the `mail` function properly, and how to write proper headers, and when to go on new line.

There is probably more errors, I suggest you to enable `display_errors` and `error_reporting` when you're developping (again, check official documentation to see how to enable it if you don't know :) )

Comment: i named function "send_message" . i used send-message funtion because they did not accept that name . in code i am using that name.

Comment: i already mentioned that this always give error on local host but  it is giving . and i read the document its like my code . in documentation they mentioned you can use array or a variable in additional header . if you can correct this code please send me  the correct code.

Comment: There is too many potential errors, that's why I told you to use display errors features that will give you error messages to help you to fix the code.

Also, keep in mind you probably can't send email from local if you didn't properly configured your local machine.
About headers, newlines are missing

Comment: can you please correct this code ? and comment what exactly you are talking about . i used error reporting function on localhost but it did not give any warning

Comment: you did not get my problem sir . i used this same code before in my 2 websites it is working properly . like this code give error on localhost and working on hosting it means code is correct. but question is why this same code not working in this site if you have any correct code which working on your computer please provide me or you correct this code and send to my .

Comment: So edit your question to replace the code by a working one : `send-message` is not a valid code. We can't help you from that.

Comment: i did this and changes to display_message